# My Host vars and Group vars are not loading

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

This is my ansible.cfg at the root of the project.

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./ansible/inventory/staging
```

This is my content of staging inventory

```
[all_hosts]
rails ansible_ssh_host=170.64.208.17

[app_hosts]
rails
```

this is my playbook:

```
- hosts: rails
  remote_user: deploy
  become: yes
  roles:
    - ruby
    - rails
```

and in my roles/ruby/main.yml. I have following code

```
- name: Install dependencies for rbenv
  package:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - git
    - curl
    - libssl-dev
    - libreadline-dev
    - zlib1g-dev
    - build-essential
    - libffi-dev
    - libyaml-dev
- name: Clone rbenv repository
  git:
    repo: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git
    dest: /home/deploy/.rbenv 
    version: master
- name: Set rbenv path
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.bashrc"
    line: 'export PATH="/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"'
    insertafter: EOF
    state: present
- name: Initialize rbenv in shell
  shell: |
    export PATH="/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
    eval "$(rbenv init -)"
- name: Clone ruby-build repository
  git:
    repo: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build
    dest: ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
    version: master
- name: Install Ruby version
  shell: |
    export PATH="/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
    eval "$(rbenv init -)"
    rbenv install {{ ruby_version }}
    rbenv global {{ ruby_version }}
- name: Debug ruby version
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ruby_version }}"
```

But it throws this:

```
fatal: [rails]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ruby_version' is undefined. 'ruby_version' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/rabin/code/web/ansible/playbooks/roles/ruby/tasks/main.yml': line 34, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    version: master\n- name: Install Ruby version\n  ^ here\n"}
```

I expect it to load variables from `ansible/host_vars/rails`

```
ruby_version: "3.2.2"
rails_env: staging
```

I also tried to load variables by defining group vars using `ansible/group_vars/app_hosts`

```
ruby_version: "3.2.2"
rails_env: staging
```

But it didn't work. Please suggest what i did wrong. I want to load them on jinga templates as well. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). There are two options for *host_vars*:

- 9.inventory host_vars/*
- 10.playbook host_vars/*

You configured the path to the inventory *./ansible/inventory/staging*. In this case, you have to put the *host_vars* also into this directory

```
./ansible/inventory/staging/host_vars/rails
```

The next option is putting the *host_vars* into the playbook's directory. This one (10.) will override the previous option (9.).

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example based on an inventory file called **`example.com`**

```ini
[app]
one.example.com
two.example.com
three.example.com
```

and `group_vars` files with content

**`group_vars/all`**

```yaml
ansible_ssh_host: 170.64.208.17
```

**`group_vars/app`**

```yaml
ruby_version: "3.2.2"
rails_env: staging
```

called via

```bash
ansible-inventory --inventory example.com --list
```

will result into an output of

```json
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "one.example.com": {
                "ansible_ssh_host": "170.64.208.17",
                "rails_env": "staging",
                "ruby_version": "3.2.2",
                "stat": true
            },
            "three.example.com": {
                "ansible_ssh_host": "170.64.208.17",
                "rails_env": "staging",
                "ruby_version": "3.2.2"
            },
            "two.example.com": {
                "ansible_ssh_host": "170.64.208.17",
                "rails_env": "staging",
                "ruby_version": "3.2.2"
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "app",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "app": {
        "hosts": [
            "one.example.com",
            "three.example.com",
            "two.example.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

To summarize, since it is not reproducible for me, you may have another look into [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html) in general and [Organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) specifically.

Please take also note that there are [Default groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#default-groups) like `all`. No need to define such differently named in the inventory again.

As shown one can test the whole inventory, group and var files just with the command [`ansible-inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-inventory.html).